# Checkbox checked not raising on change event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, checkbox

I am calling `function testing(id)` that adds label check box. but when i am checking the checkbox on change event not getting raised

```
function testing(id) {
    $('.todo-card').prepend('<div class="todo-task"> ' +
    '<input type="checkbox" id="'+id+'"/> '+
    '<label for="'+id+'">'+$("#todoadd").val()+' <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete"></span> '+
    '</label> </div> ');
}

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            });
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
              alert("asdasdada");
          });
 <script>
```

Comment: Your HTML isn't right.

Comment: You need to show more of your HTML to clear up what you are doing wrong, both suggested answers should work unless for some reason your HTML is poor structured and/or you are missing the jQuery library.

Comment: Can you show your .net code? Is there any change your HTML appending dynamically ( after document ready )?

Answer (score 0):

Asign events with a delegate method, and not directly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function() {
        alert($(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

By this mode, when you add a new line the event will be executed again.

Comment: i am adding the checkboxes and labels dynamically with id each check boxes starts from 1 checkbox1,checkbox2 etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter, this code `input[type=checkbox]` selects all checkbox no matter what id it has. If this doesn't work, maybe you need to share us more pieces of code